# how to use dependency injection with hilt for kotlin

Tags: android

how to solve this problem

Schema export directory was not provided to the annotation processor so Room cannot export the schema. You can either provide `room.schemaLocation` annotation processor argument by applying the Room Gradle plugin (id 'androidx.room') OR set exportSchema to false.

I would like to solve the problem.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

It's just warning telling you that you have `exportSchema=true` in your `@Database` but you didn't specify directory where to export. It's related to **androidx Room** and not to hilt or kotlin.

You can specify schema like this, put it in your app `build.gradle` in `defaultConfig` block:

**Kotlin gradle**

```kotlin
android {
    defaultConfig {
           javaCompileOptions {
            annotationProcessorOptions {
                arguments["room.schemaLocation"] = "${projectDir.path}/schemas"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Groovy gradle**

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        javaCompileOptions {
            annotationProcessorOptions {
                arguments = ["room.schemaLocation": "$projectDir/schemas".toString()]
            }
        }
    }
}
```